# How can I display all records created by a user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, list, activerecord

I have a table of users, venues and reviews where a user can have many reviews and a venue has many reviews.

How can I go about displaying all the reviews written by a user on each users show page?

I'm currently displaying the reviews written by users on the associated venue show pages using this bit of code:

```
<%= render :partial => 'reviews/review', :collection => @venue.reviews %>
```

Is it possible to reuse the review partial for this?

Using:

```
<%= render :partial => 'reviews/review', :collection => @user.reviews %>
```

in the user show page gives a undefined method `review_path' error.

Thanks for any help its much appreciated!

**edit**

**Review partial**

```
<div class="review">

  <div class="reviewer_details">
    <div class="reviewer_details_photo">
      <%= image_tag review.user.avatar.url(:thumb) %>
    </div>
    <%= review.user.username %>
  </div>

  <div class="review_content">
    <h2 class="review_partial_title"><%= link_to review.title, [@venue, review] %></h><br>
    <p><%= review.rating %></p>
  </div>

  <div class="clearall"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That review_path error is most likely comming from the partial. Can you post the code of reviews/review ?

Comment: @Devin M, Thanks for having a look I've added the partial to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `review` only has one `venue`, right?

So try replacing `link_to review.title, [@venue, review]` with

`link_to review.title, [review.venue, review]`

As @Devin said, `@venue` is `nil` in your user-directed reviews list.

Answer (score 1):

When you call that partial you are not passing an @venue.
Try changing `<%= link_to review.title, [@venue, review] %>`
To something a little more broad like `<%= link_to review.title, [object, review] %>`

And in your calls to this partial use

```
<%= render :partial => 'reviews/review', :collection => @user.reviews, :locals => {:object => @user} %>
```